# How to construct a non-diagonalizable matrix with a particular set of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a set of eigenvalues, how would you go about constructing a matrix with those particular eigenvalues?

I know that you can construct a diagonalizable matrix with those eigenvalues using a linearly independent basis vector $B$:

$$M=B^{-1}\Lambda{B}$$

But is there any way to construct a non-diagonalizable matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is not diagonalisable, it must have repeated eigenvalues.
Put the eigenvalues along the diagonal, and put ones above the diagonal when the eigenvalues are equal: $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&1&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&2\end{array}\right]$

Comment: Can a matrix with repeated eigenvalues be diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes, any diagonal matrix which has repeated entries along the diagonal is a diagonalizable matrix with repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Try the identity matrix.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The rotation matrix $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$ has distinct eigenvalues, but it is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Nor over $\mathbb{Z}$.  But it is diagonalizable.